# Верстка при помощи Bootstrap

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap

Есть вопрос по поводу того как лучше организовать этот кусок на странице(там где квадрат с досками):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть идея как это сделать, но я не знаю на сколько она рациональна:
Внутри колонки создать новый блок, для него сделать background-image квадрат на котором контент и сделать размер этого блока как размер background-image.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
    <div class="back"></div>
</div>



 .back{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 1032px;
    height: 640px;
    background-image: url("images/content-box.png");
    }
```

ну тогда у меня обрезается нижняя честь background
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тогда встает вопрос как добавлять остальной контент, внутри div.back создавать еще блоки и как-то их позиционировать?

Comment: мульти фон ,абсолютные блоки - вроде всё, и так можно и в другом случае тоже можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я посоветовал бы посмотреть в сторону в последней версии это class="card", а в предыдущих это class="panel", в принципе они гибко настраиваются под практически все возможные задачи, я с помощью них решал у себя